# How to get correct phase values of the signal using Recursive Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fft, dft, phase

### Question

I'm trying to understand the relation of the result of the recursive DFT to the original signal. I have a signal with a sampling frequency of 4000 Hz and the recursive phasor estimation algorithm, which is based on the following expression:
$$\dot{X_{k}}=\dot{X_{k-1}}+\frac{2}{N}\cdot(X_{k}-X_{k-N})\cdot e^{-\omega t}$$
where $N = 80$ - samples per cycle of the power frequency.

After applying the algorithm I get Complex values of phasor. Next I extract the magnitude (or absolute value) and the phase of a complex number using built-in c# functions. Results for the amplitude look correct. But as seen from the plot the phase values look strange in the range of 0.0243-0.0303. What could be the reason for this behavior? How to extract correct values for phase?

[image]

I am new at signal processing, any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

### Answer

As mentioned @PeterK. the thing is that a phase jump occurs when the difference between two adjacent phase value entries exceeds the value of the π.

To override this behavior you can use built-in functions (e.g. [numphy.unwrap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html) or [unwrap block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/unwrap.html)) or implement this code:

```
    public double UnwrapPhaseRadians(double currentPhase, double prevPhase)
    {
        int k = 0;

        double dif = currentPhase - prevPhase;

        if (dif >= Math.PI)
        {
            if (currentPhase < prevPhase)
            {
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                k--;
            }
        }

        return currentPhase + 2 * Math.PI * k;
    }
```

Using this method allows you to unwrap the phase so that it is continuous, without jumps. The method takes 2 arguments - current and previous phase value, compares them and add 2*π*k to the current phase value if a phase jump is detected. Remember that method works with values in radians.

I hope that it might be helpful to others! And thanks to @PeterK.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  I've closed your question because, to me, it seems like it's just a problem with phase unwrapping (read about that in the duplicate).  While the "duplicate" might not ask exactly the same question you're asking, I think its answer resolves your problem too. Ping me if you think this is not correct and we can figure out what the right answer is.

Comment: @PeterK. Thank you for the quick response. I use built-in c# function to return the phase angle of the complex number. For a complex number a + bi, the phase is computed as Math.Atan2(b, a). In my case the angle is in the range [-180, 180)

Comment: Right!  So the phase value at 0.0243 is very close to -180 degrees (-$\pi$ radians).  And that function can't tell the difference (much) between -180 degrees and +180 degrees. So once it goes "more negative" than -180, it flips to +180 degrees. You need to not only use the four-quadrant `atan` function like you are, you also need to do [phase unwrapping](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Phase_Unwrapping.html).

Comment: @PeterK. Thank you, Peter! I've updated my code and added the method, which unwraps the phase so that it is continuous, without jumps. I'm going to add this method to my question in case somebody will look for the unwrap function realization

Comment: Please add this as an answer to your own question! That's the best way to leave information for future readers. I've reopened the question so you can do that.

Comment: @ Sakayevas. Can you tell us the origin of your Xk equation? (I've never seen that equation before.)

Comment: @RichardLyons Frankly, I utilize the already existing algorithm, but I've found a similar equation in the book "Synchronized Phasor Measurements and Their Applications" by Arun G. Phadke and James S. Thorp (p. 33 eq. 2.9). Does this equation look weird?

Comment: @ Sakayevas. I'm familiar with an algorithm called the "Sliding Discrete Fourier Transform" (SDFT) for computing single DFT bin values on a real-time basis. That algorithm involves computations using time-domain samples. Your equation appears to only use frequency-domain samples in its computations, and that surprised me because I've never seen your equation before. As time permits, in the future, I hope to experiment with and study your equation.